# Не записывается ID пользователя в .txt

Tags: python, telegram, бот

я написал функцию в боте которая при команде /start записывает ID пользователя в baza.txt.
Позже через эти ID я могу рассылать сообщения юзерам. 
Все отлично работает кроме записи этих ID. Вот элемент кода который выполняет эти действия.

```py
baza = open("baza/baza.txt", "r")
bazaUsers = set ()
for line in baza:
    bazaUsers.add(line.strip())
baza.close()
```

Comment: Что именно не работает? Проверьте, верная ли индентация в вашем коде. Приведенный код ничего не записывает, только считывает уникальные строки из файла.

Comment: обратите внимание на аргументы функции open

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для записи данных в файл нужно сделать вот так:

```py
# подразумевается, что функция get_users возвращает некоторый список ID
bazaUsers = get_users() 

# открывается файл в режиме записи и в него записываются все ID на отдельных строках
with open("baza/baza.txt", "w") as baza:
    baza.write('\n'.join(bazaUsers))
```

Comment: пишет что get_users не найдено, что нужно в код дописать?

Comment: Ну ты бы хоть комментарий к этой строчке прочёл что ли! Подразумевается, что эта функция возвращает список user_id. Я без понятия, как ты их получаешь. Подставь вместо этой функции свой метод получения данных.